# Python extend function not working - not sure why

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following code where I want to add the string 'NSQscores' to the list of strings 'newlist'.

However, the following code gives me a 'none'.

```
columnlist = list(newdf.columns)
newlist = columnlist[0:87]
newlist2 = newlist.extend(['NSQscores'])
print(newlist2)

none
```

Would be so grateful if anybody could give me a helping hand!

As an example:

```
newlist[5:10]

['military-quantised',
 'mental_imagery-quantised',
 'navigate_growup-quantised',
 'independent_nav-quantised',
 'response-1 -quantised']
```

Comment: `list.extend` always returns `None`. Its purpose is to mutate the list in-place.

Comment: @PaulM. how can I add onto the list? :)

Comment: `newlist = columnlist[0:87] + ['NSQscores']`

Answer (score 1):

`x.extend` modifies `x` in place and returns `None`. So you added an element to `newlist` and set `newlist2` to None.

Try `newlist2 = newlist + ['NSQscores']`. Or just use `newlist` instead of creating another one.

Answer (score 1):

.extend is a mutator, so it will modify newlist and not return anything.
you can just do `newlist.extend(["NSQscores"])` without assigning the output to anything

As a sidenote, you'd probably be better served with the .append method with something like this: `newlist.append("NSQscores")` if you're only adding single items. (It's still a mutator like extend, so it returns nothing, but designed specificially for adding a single value)